# Password protecting certain endpoints/resources

Tags: php, rest

I'm building a REST API for part of a folder/file browser application.

One of the aspects of the design is the ability to password protect a folder and I'm just wondering what the best practise would be for this.

My folders table has an is_protected boolean and a password field which will be stored encrypted. This is optional protection.

The developer would send a GET request to http://my-website/api/v1/folders/1 and the backend returns the resource as JSON.

However, if the folder is password protected, I need to check if the password matches. Is it best to maybe send this in the HTTP Header? Or a session using the unique folder slug as the key or something?

All suggestions welcome, cheers!

Comment: the easiest solution would be http basic auth, with .htacess and .htpasswd

Comment: I'm building something similar - did you come up with a solution for this?  I'm already using basic authentication to access the service in general, but some file resources have passwords associated with them so even on a GET request the password would need to be sent as part of the request in order to retrieve the file's metadata.

Comment: @Amber I've started using JWTs now. There's a pretty good overview at https://stormpath.com/blog/token-auth-spa/. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your REST API should create a login service, which will take a username / password, and respond with an Authorization token to be used on subsequent requests.. `Authorization: token 98wuun8EIU23H8D3D87dow7dh` this token should also have an expiry date at which point will need to be refreshed,  your app should not pass Username / password on the resource request itself.

The auth token itself should be unique to every user, and on refresh should generate a completely new unique token.  Then your token can be used to identify the user on the backend.

refreshing can be done by a refresh token, or by asking the user to enter their username / password again and requesting a new Auth token..

Also ensure your production environment uses SSL to reduce man-in-the-middle type of attacks.